# Vuejs transition is not working to show a modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am at a loss to why my animation is not working using vue transitions.  Here is my code:

```
 <template>
  <teleport to="body">
    <div class="modal-overlay" v-if="loading">
      <transition name="loading">
        <div v-if="loading" class="dialog">
          <h1>LOADING</h1>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </teleport>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["loading"],
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.dialog {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  border: 2px solid #00f6f6;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  color: #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
  /* animation: enter 0.25s linear; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-overlay {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.loading-enter-active {
  animation: enter 0.2s ease-out;
}

.loading-leave-active {
  animation: leave 0.2s ease-in;
}



@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0%;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes leave {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}
</style>
```

I am passing a prop from the parent component called "loading".  This serves as a modal and it serves the purpose as the modal is it does appear and disappear based on the value of "loading" but the animation is not working.  Can anyone tell me why?

Thank you!

Comment: You're using `scoped` attribute on your `<style>` tag but you're teleporting the contents on `<body>`. Place the CSS into an non-scoped style tag and use a unique class to avoid your selectors applying to other parts of your app/page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have `v-if="loading"` on `.modal-overlay`. This doesn't give it a chance to evaluate the condition and transition the element.

Remove that and it should work:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false
    }
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.loading = !this.loading
    }, 2000)
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.dialog {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  min-width: fit-content;
  border: 2px solid #00f6f6;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  color: #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
  /* animation: enter 0.25s linear; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-overlay {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.loading-enter-active {
  animation: enter 0.2s ease-out;
}

.loading-leave-active {
  animation: enter 0.2s ease-in reverse;
}

@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0%;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <teleport to="body">
    <div class="modal-overlay">
      <transition name="loading">
        <div class="dialog" v-if="loading">
          <h1>LOADING</h1>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </teleport>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes of course! I knew it would be something obvious like this.  The goal is to have it all appear together so instead I just made it so the dialog is not nested within the overlay and then positioned them accordingly, which now works perfect.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was facing similar problem when i was using Modal. From your question, i understood that you have problem with the transition, that is because of the `<style scoped>`.

You can go through this link https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#referencing-assets for better understanding how the CSS works in Vue/cli projects.

I am not sure why you have used `<div v-if="loading" class="dialog">`, first remove the v-if and then try adding a class to CSS `<style lang="scss" scoped>`.

If this is working fine for you, then you can add v-if or anything according to your requirements.

Thank you, I hope this will help you.